# Applying :nth-child to elements regardless of their different parents

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm looking for a way to apply the :nth-child approach to elements that are spread over different parents / containers (but it seems to count back from 0 with every container):

```
<div class="downloads">
    <div class="views-field views-field-view">
        <span class="field-content">
            <div class="view">
                <div class="view-content">
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 1 -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 2 -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 3 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-view-1">
        <span class="field-content">
            <div class="view">
                <div class="view-content">
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 4: should have a background-color (but nth:-approach counts this back as 1) -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 5 -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 6 -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 7 -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 8: should have a background-color -->
                    <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 9 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/6dkos5fy/1/) a bit around, and the strange thing is: it works with `:nth-child(3n+3)`, but i need every *fourth* element to be affected, and that's where it goes wrong. When I use `:nth-child(4n+4)` it would only apply it to one element of the nine that are displayed:

```
.downloads .col:nth-child(4n+4) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Can someone help me out with this please? 
http://jsfiddle.net/6dkos5fy/1/

[jQuery approach](http://jsfiddle.net/6dkos5fy/6/) works for me. Thanks Alex!

```
var i = 1;
$(".downloads .col").each(function() {
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
  i++;
});

.active {
   background: yellow;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is kind hard with you html structure. I create the following using `.views-field-view-1` element to separate the containers. `:nth-child` is not working the way you looking:

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the
>   selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in
>   the series of children matches the pattern an+b.

```css
.downloads .views-field-view-1 .col:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="downloads">
  <div class="views-field views-field-view">
    <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 1 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 2 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-view-1">
    <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 4: should have a background-color (but nth:-approach counts this as 1) -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 5 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 6 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 7 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 8: should have a background-color -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 9 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For a better understanding check the following snippet:

```css
.downloads .views-field-view-1 .col:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: yellow;
}
.downloads .col {
  counter-increment: box;
}
.downloads .col:after {
  content: counter(box);
}
```

```html
<div class="downloads">
  <div class="views-field views-field-view"> <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 1 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 2 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>

  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-view-1"> <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 4: should have a background-color (but nth:-approach counts this as 1) -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 5 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 6 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 7 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 8: should have a background-color -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 9 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

After your comment with jquery you can try:

```js
var i = 1;
$(".downloads .col").each(function() {
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
  i++;
});
```

```css
 .active {
   background: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="downloads">
  <div class="views-field views-field-view"> <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 1 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 2 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>

  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-view-1"> <span class="field-content">
   <div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 4: should have a background-color (but nth:-approach counts this as 1) -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 5 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 6 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 7 -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 8: should have a background-color -->
     <div class="col col-xs-3">text</div> <!-- 9 -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

**References**

[:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your kind help, but since these are dynamic elements (extra `.col`'s can be added to either `views-field-view` and `views-field-view-1`), I need a more future proof approach. Would there be something I could do with jQuery instead?

Comment: @cptstarling Check my jquery approach.

Comment: @cptstarling Glad that I helped you.